# How to construct domain model from persistence store? #DDD

Tags: model, architecture, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, ddd-service

I am trying to learn domain-driven design (DDD). And I don't understand how to construct domain model from the persistence store. I am making my domain models without public setters in order to keep my states safe and consistent, but ,on the other hand, to construct them from persistence store I need to have those setters. In "Implementing DDD", it is possible as long as I use ORM tools. But what if I don't want to use ORM, actually I want to use NoSQL. I might use Event Sourcing. If you guys have any better suggestions. What is the best practice in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it doesn't matter what database you use, so you can use an SQL database or a NoSQL, the same applies for ORM or a low level client.

What your repository needs to do is collect the data and pass it to the constructor of your domain models, so the public setters are not necessary. I'm adding some pseudocode with a simple example:

```
class UserEntity:
  public function constructor(name, email)
    this._set_name(name)
    this._set_email(email)

  private function _set_name(name)
    this.name = name

  private function _set_email(email)
    this.email = email


class Repository:
  public static function get_by_email(a_email)
    row = client.sql("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE email=%", a_email)
    return UserEntity(name=row["name"], email=row["email"])
```

Comment: Yes, it possible but it violates encapsulation as same as setters. What do you think about setting private fields using reflection like hibernate

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "violates encapsulation"?

Comment: I follow Uuganbold in that hydrating your domain model through a constructor might break encapsulation. Let's say there are certain private properties that can only be changed through methods that encapsulate some business requirements. Hydrating this property with a constructor might allow it to have a value that does not meet these business requirements.

Comment: @Thogor how was data persisted, if it does not comply with business requirements? Data should be validated before being persisted. Even in case when business requirement changed. and persisted data becomes invalid, it should not be a task of repository to validate the data, but the domain model itself, because it is its data.

Comment: @fathineos In your example a repository method knows about domain model, but it should be the other way around, domain model should use (reference) repository to get its data (amongst other CRUD operations). Also, if your repository method is static, how are you going to mock it in tests?

Comment: @Goran I agree that data should be valid before being persisted. The public methods that encapsulate business requirements will make sure of that. Let's say that there is a "status" property that can only be changed to "Done" by first calling method1() and then method2(). Having this status property in your constructor, makes it possible for other developers to instantiate your object with "Done" without calling "method1()" and "method2()" first. By letting hibernate using reflection to hydrate the private property, we make sure that "status" can only be "Done" after calling the above methods.

Comment: @Thogor I still do not see how private property is the problem here, nor do I understand what problem do you see with misusing Done property. If Done property is property which value is persisted, then user will pass data got from persistence layer (through repository), including the value of Done However, if Done property is a result calculated by some Method (and therefore not persisted), then only the domain object can set this property, and it will not be passed  from persistance layer at all (as data).

Comment: +1 to @Goran's answer.

> "Having this status property in your constructor, makes it possible for other developers to instantiate your object with "Done" without calling "method1()" and "method2()" first.

This is just fine to do so, as far as the object is the same as before.

Comment: @Goran Are you sure that the domain model should know about the repository? In the Vaughn Vernon's example this isn't true.
[Repository](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/05d95572f2ad6b85357b216d7d617b27359a360d/iddd_agilepm/src/main/java/com/saasovation/agilepm/port/adapter/persistence/LevelDBSprintRepository.java#L68-L77), 

[Domain Model](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/05d95572f2ad6b85357b216d7d617b27359a360d/iddd_agilepm/src/main/java/com/saasovation/agilepm/domain/model/product/sprint/Sprint.java).

Comment: @fathineos From the DDD purist perspective, repository calls would be handled outside of business model, in the application layer. This really brings benefit when you build application for multiple devices, ex application logic in MVVM desktop application  could differentiate than MVC web application logic. So, that is why in my last paragraph I talked about not passing repository to ctor. DDD should be a guidance, when you understand why is something required, and when to use it, its easier to make a choice.

Comment: @fathineos, I agree that it's fine to use the constructor as long as the object is the same as before. My point is that it's not a guarantee. Nothing is checking if the requirements of m1() and m2() are being met if you just pass it through the constructor. As said before, any developer has access to this constructor and so can pass anything to it. It's not a big problem though, considering that developers tend to be cautious and there is a review process in place.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mixing domain models with data transfer objects (DTO). Repository does not use (reference) domain models, it uses DTOs.

Normally you would pass IRepository instance to ctor of business model object, and then model itself can use repository to get the data (in form of DTOs), set its private properties directly, or use its methods to validate data, if required by business. You pass IRepository instance because you would probably need to save data also, not just load it. So, in order for business object to be able to know how to persist validated data, it needs reference to repository instance.

Or, if you want to be really pure about this, and not passing the repository instance, and leave loading / saving to the application layer, then you would call repository.Getxxx somewhere in application layer and pass data (as DTOs) to business model ctor.

Comment: Thank you, you are suggesting Active Record Pattern? I am using Data Mapper. That might be good option though.

Comment: @UuganboldTsegmed No, I was suggesting repository pattern instead, which is used to decouple the business model layer from the persistence (storage) layer.

Comment: @UuganboldTsegmed Btw, when you talk about data mapper, in my understanding that should just be an intermediary layer (a mediator service) that maps data from domain model to DTOs (repository data), and vice versa, no matter if data maps to 1on1, or domain model differs from the database structure (object relational impedance mismatch).

Answer (score 0):

> How to construct domain model from the persistence store?

My advice: if your domain is a bit complex, don't do that.

A DB model is a model designed in order to store data. If you generate your domain model from this, the result will be an [anemic model](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html): entities without any behavior.
A domain model designed with DDD principles in mind will result in a rich model made of entities and value objects with behaviors. Those behaviors will help you to achieve the use cases that belongs to a particular bounded context.

That being said, if your bounded context is CRUD only with no domain complexity, this is a totally valid approach. Remember that DDD does not force any architecture choice. You have plenty of tactical patterns that you might want to use or not depending on your bounded context complexity.